# Decrement of element values ".prev()" button without the active class

Tags: javascript, jquery

The script works in such a way that after clicking on the button it gives it the active class and increments the value of the .prev () element. However, I would like to click on another element and give it an active class, only its value was incremented. The rest should be reduced by 1, but I do not know how I could do it.

```js
click = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

$(".reaction-btn").on("click", function() {

  index = $(this).parents(".reaction").index(".reaction");
  $(".reaction-btn").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

  if (click[index] % 2 == 0) {
    $(this).prev().text(parseInt($(this).prev().text()) + 1);
  } else {
    $(this).prev().text(parseInt($(this).prev().text()) - 1);
  }

  click[index]++;

});
```

```css
.active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="reaction">
  <span class="reaction-counter">1</span>
  <button type="button" class="reaction-btn">Good</button>
</section>

<section class="reaction">
  <span class="reaction-counter">1</span>
  <button type="button" class="reaction-btn">Super</button>
</section>

<section class="reaction">
  <span class="reaction-counter">1</span>
  <button type="button" class="reaction-btn">Nice</button>
</section>

<section class="reaction">
  <span class="reaction-counter">1</span>
  <button type="button" class="reaction-btn">Bad</button>
</section>

<section class="reaction">
  <span class="reaction-counter">1</span>
  <button type="button" class="reaction-btn">Very bad</button>
</section>
```

Comment: It will help if you can share a sample flow in terms of what should happen- *when I click on Good* and *when I click on Nice*..., etc.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand from the code and the text that you have shared. Can you add more details to it ?

Comment: @Saurabh What details do you need? I just want to increase only one value when clicking a button, not each one separately.

Comment: @montana So once a value has increased and you click on another button, what should happen to value of button which was increased earlier on click?

Comment: So you want to increment the value of clicked element and side-by-side also decrement the value of rest of the `.reaction-btn` elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The rest should be reduced by 1, but I do not know how I could do it.

Looks like you want to **increment the value of clicked element** and side-by-side also **decrement the value of rest of the `.reaction-btn` elements**.

```
//reduce all reaction-btn value by 1
  $(".reaction-btn").not( this ).each( function(){
      $(this).prev().text( +$(this).prev().text() - 1 );
  });

  //increment clicked element value
  $(this).prev().text( +$(this).prev().text() + 1 );
```

**Demo**

```js
click = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

$(".reaction-btn").on("click", function() {

  //reduce all reaction-btn value by 1
  $(".reaction-btn").not( this ).each( function(){
      $(this).prev().text( +$(this).prev().text() - 1 );
  });
  
  //increment clicked element value
  $(this).prev().text( +$(this).prev().text() + 1 );
  
  $(".reaction-btn").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="reaction">
  <span class="reaction-counter">1</span>
  <button type="button" class="reaction-btn">Good</button>
</section>

<section class="reaction">
  <span class="reaction-counter">1</span>
  <button type="button" class="reaction-btn">Super</button>
</section>

<section class="reaction">
  <span class="reaction-counter">1</span>
  <button type="button" class="reaction-btn">Nice</button>
</section>

<section class="reaction">
  <span class="reaction-counter">1</span>
  <button type="button" class="reaction-btn">Bad</button>
</section>

<section class="reaction">
  <span class="reaction-counter">1</span>
  <button type="button" class="reaction-btn">Very bad</button>
</section>
```

Or if you only want to decrement last clicked element, then

```
 //reduce all active reaction-btn value by 1
  $(".reaction-btn.active").not( this ).each( function(){
      $(this).prev().text( +$(this).prev().text() - 1 );
  });
```

**Demo**

```js
click = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

$(".reaction-btn").on("click", function() {

  //reduce all active reaction-btn value by 1
  $(".reaction-btn.active").not( this ).each( function(){
      $(this).prev().text( +$(this).prev().text() - 1 );
  });
  
  //increment clicked element value
  $(this).prev().text( +$(this).prev().text() + 1 );
  
  $(".reaction-btn").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="reaction">
  <span class="reaction-counter">1</span>
  <button type="button" class="reaction-btn">Good</button>
</section>

<section class="reaction">
  <span class="reaction-counter">1</span>
  <button type="button" class="reaction-btn">Super</button>
</section>

<section class="reaction">
  <span class="reaction-counter">1</span>
  <button type="button" class="reaction-btn">Nice</button>
</section>

<section class="reaction">
  <span class="reaction-counter">1</span>
  <button type="button" class="reaction-btn">Bad</button>
</section>

<section class="reaction">
  <span class="reaction-counter">1</span>
  <button type="button" class="reaction-btn">Very bad</button>
</section>
```